# Visual Studio massive renaming of controls in WPF project

Tags: wpf, visual-studio

I have a scene in my WPF project with about 2000 different user controls:

```
<local:MyControlType x:name="aaka4sn9f" />
<local:MyControlType x:name="aaks22nf_1" />
<local:MyControlType x:name="aa66s2f_2" />
```

and so on down the screen...

Is there a way to rename all of these controls using Visual Studio (and possibly a regex) to be:

```
<local:MyControlType x:name="myControl1" />
<local:MyControlType x:name="myControl2" />
<local:MyControlType x:name="myControl3" />
```

??

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Visual Studio has Regex capability in its search (and replace). Press `Ctrl+H`, expand "Find Options" and click the bottom-most checkbox, "Use." Make sure "regular expressions" is selected.

I don't think you'll be able to get the increments going using this technique, but you can name all the controls the same thing, like "myControlx", then use a regex to search (not replace) for, say `x"`. You can then quickly move to each location using `F3` and enter the numbers.

If you have any experience with more "featureful" text editors, like Vim, open the xaml file in that and make the changes.

#### Edit:

Using Vim this can be done in two commands (but you'll need to install the increment.vim plugin from here: http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=842).

`:%s/x:name="\zs.\{-}\ze"/myControl@/g` *(replaces x:name attributes with `myControl@`)*
`:%Inc` *(replaces all `@` with an incremented integer)*

Comment: I have used some powerful editors before, but I still wouldn't know how to do it using one of them

Comment: @Mark, I updated the answer to include one (of many, no doubt) way of doing this in Vim. ViEmu is a very nice Vim emulator that runs as a plugin in Visual Studio, but the current version does not support incrementing.

Comment: Thanks Jay, I ended up using Vim for windows and used the Inc command (although I had to use it like: `:%Inc s4001` simply because I did not want to start at zero)

Answer (score 0):

2000?! Do they actually *need* names? Does your code-behind/data bindings really refer to 2000 different controls?

Comment: well I was going to also apply this technique to give them unique properties